# Function from Another .js File Not Working

Tags: javascript

I want to display the date on my page. When I made a few functions in the `<script>` tag, the code works fine. I want to put those two functions in another .js file so the code doesn't look as messy. But when I do that, the functions don't seem to work. My index.html and custom.js are in the same folder. Is there anything I am doing wrong? Thanks!
My simplified index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="custom.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
        document.write('<h1>' + returnWeek() + ', ' + returnMonth(false) + ' ' + new Date().getDate() + ', ' + new Date().getFullYear() + '</h1> <small>' + returnMonth(true) + '.' + new Date().getDate() + '.' + new Date().getFullYear() + '</small>');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My custom.js:

```
function returnWeek() {
    switch (new Date().getDay()) {
        case 0:
            return 'Sunday';
        case 1:
            return 'Monday';
        case 2:
            return 'Tuesday';
        case 3:
            return 'Wednesday';
        case 4:
            return 'Thursday';
        case 5:
            return 'Friday';
        case 6:
            return 'Saturday';
    }
}
function returnMonth(num) {
    if (num == true) {
        return new Date().getMonth() + 1;
    } else {
        switch (new Date().getMonth()) {
            case 0:
                return 'January';
            case 1:
                return 'February';
            case 2:
                return 'March';
            case 3:
                return 'April';
            case 4:
                return 'May';
            case 5:
                return 'June';
            case 6:
                return 'July';
            case 7:
                return 'August';
            case 8:
                return 'September';
            case 9:
                return 'October';
            case 10:
                return 'November';
            case 11:
                return 'December';
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Click [here](http://pastebin.com/Td7QWzNw) for the full code! I originally had the contents of the custom.js right above the document.write() for the date.

Comment: try refreshing the page or clearing browser cache - a previous version of the js file without your functions may have been cached on the client

Comment: Still doesn't work :I

Comment: What's the error? Is nothing happening are you getting anything on developer tools for browser. Does a simple alert function work from file. That will decide wether it's code or linkage

Comment: Try loading your page in a fresh Incognito or Private mode browser, those will have a clean and fresh cache that should demonstrate everything working properly.

Comment: @Creaven I believe the error is linkage. There are other javascript components like a clock that will work on the page.

Comment: If the functions only work in the index.php, I think I might just keep them in there and not use an external js file. Maybe I'll try to fix it later if I really _need_ to. But I appreciate everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code on Opera, Firefox 35.0.1, Chrome and IE 11 by calling the external .js file; it is perfect as it returns the date according to my machine date. So please check your browsers and as Igor suggested clean cache.

Comment: Hmm, maybe the other components are interrupting it? I wouldn't think so but this is [the actual code](http://pastebin.com/Td7QWzNw).

Comment: Sorry i was away; if it is still not figured out i can give it a try.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried clearing my cache and going into private browsing, but it still doesn't work. If I have a function that alerts "hi" in the custom.js file, it will not work. But if I have an alert() directly in the <script>, everything works fine. Anything else that might solve this linkage issue? Or maybe I need to do something different with the functions in the custom.js file? Or another way to call functions in another file?

Comment: I'm also using PHP for some stuff, so I'm using a MAMP server on my desktop

Comment: Linking external js file requires exact path with the syntax <script src="Your file path name"></script>; if you are not using any IDE use double quotes to save your .js file for example "yourFile.js"

Comment: I'm using brackets and I'm using <srcipt src="custom.js"></srcipt> to add the js file. The actual file itself is not named "custom.js" though :P

Comment: Well this is what we can do at max with given code and scenirio, as you can see on jsfiddle every thing is good.

Comment: For details  javascript function invocation please go [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that what is happening is your HTML file is loading faster than your JS file.  By executing the code immediately (even though it's at the bottom of your HTML file), it is likely getting hung up because those methods technically haven't loaded yet.  Try executing your code after the page loads.

```
function initPage () {
    document.write('<h1>' + returnWeek() + ', ' + returnMonth(false) + ' ' + new Date().getDate() + ', ' + new Date().getFullYear() + '</h1> <small>' + returnMonth(true) + '.' + new Date().getDate() + '.' + new Date().getFullYear() + '</small>');
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", initPage, false);
} else {
    window.onload = initPage;
}
```

Comment: Scripts load synchronously unless otherwise specified, so the contents of that file should immediately be available. It sounds like an old custom.js is just being cached hard like others have suggested.

Comment: Bah, nvm, that shouldn't be a problem unless you told the browser to load the external script file asynchronously. ie: <script src="..." async=true></script> (edit: @BrianArnold beat me to it lol)